# Active Directory Server out of service with LSASS.exe using more than 50% of CPU

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, anti-virus

My DC (Windows Server 2003 R2) randomly goes offline denying all requests and writing on the System Event log an error 2019 from source SRV "The server was unable to allocate from the system nonpaged pool because the pool was empty". The machine is up to date with all latest update, and it is running AVG9, also this latest update and latest signatures. With a AV scan, nothing strange. How can this stop solved? On google i can find no useful solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this MS article to successfully troubleshoot a high cpu on a DC. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727054.aspx

Because this problem comes back when you build another DC there must be an external factor that is acting upon the server and spiking the processor. You should be able to prove this by  unplugging the network cable on the DC. If after more than 15 minutes if the cpu drops to almost nothing you can start looking for external services and accounts that connected to that DC.

MS's Active Directory team also has a more extensive post on there blog. http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2007/08/20/troubleshooting-high-lsass-cpu-utilization-on-a-domain-controller-part-1-of-2.aspx

Comment: the problems was internal because after the removal of the AVG Anti Virus the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this specific problem, but there are some good looking comments at [eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=2019&eventno=661&source=Srv&phase=1)

Comment: already seen, no one of the comments were useful to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Any other relevant info in the logs have you installed/updated drivers or an Anti virus program recently?

Comment: no, no other problems or errors

Answer (score 0):

If this machine is just running as a DC then I would be recommending *very* strongly that you build another DC, sync it up\transfer roles and then shut down the misbehaving server.

Comment: this problem appeared also on the new dc i built to replace another one. the older one did not have the problem.

Comment: Can you list all 3rd party\non standard software (apart from AVG) that's running on your DC, any custom scripts that are scheduled on the system and do you have anything running in your domain that is making sustained AD queries?

Comment: no other sw other than standard windows setup + avg. The servers are not used for the external applications query